# Junit Transactional makes newly inserted rows invisible when read?

Tags: sql, database, transactional

I run my test case with @Transactional annotation. In one of my test methods I do something in service layer and this results in storing a new row in the database. But when I want to use that
row in same method (just to test the integrity of the data put in the database) it cannot be found.
I suppose the database never gets updated before the method ends? How to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add isolation level to the @Transactional attribute as

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

That will allow the uncommitted reads from the database that the test is currently not seeing.